# models to use for Recursive Feature Elimination for classification and regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, classification, feature-selection

which models can we use for `Recursive Feature Elimination` for `classification` and `regression`.

For example we can use

```
selector = RFE(RandomForestClassifier(), 5)
```

for classification 
and

```
selector = RFE(RandomForestRegressor(), 5)
```

for regression

1. **What other models can be used for RFE**?
2. **Can Regression RFE models be used for Classification and vice-versa** (Read it somewhere. Still unsure how do they fit in)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Q.1, the documentation is stating:

> estimator : object
>
> A supervised learning estimator with a fit method that provides information about feature importance either through a coef_ attribute or through a feature_importances_ attribute.

`coef_` are generally associated with all linear models (e.g. `sklearn.linear_model`, `sklearn.naive_baye`, `sklearn.svm`, etc.). `feature_importances_` are associated with tree-based model: e.g. `sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier`, `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`, etc.

Regarding Q.2, I don't know enough about this. I would have the intuition that you could use some classifiers for a regression problem by discretizing the problem but not sure that it would be helpful in practice. I would let somebody more knowledgeable answer to this question.